# Processing audio in AVAudioengine framework

Tags: swift, avaudioengine

I'm trying to make an app for OSX that I've already prototyped with Max MSP. Because of my limited programming knowledge, it have to be 100% swift (no C or C++).

I'm investigating with AVAudioengine framework and I'm stuck with some capabilities I need:

I have a player that reproduces stereo audio files. I want a mixer with options for muting left or right channel independently, mono sum left and right channels, and invert phase of left or right channel independently.

I would like a confirmation that it's possible and some advices about the direction to follow.

Comment: Try [AudioKit](https://audiokit.io)!

Comment: I've been playing a little with AudioKit. Could you give me an example of a node chain that will allow me to make some maths on the signal at some point?